# Not sure how to debug `uid: prismicDocument.uid ?? void 0` with Prismic and Next.js site

Tags: javascript, next.js, prismic.io

I have a Next.js project that uses the [Prismic](https://prismic.io/) CMS, and the site works locally just fine, but recently someone changed some copy in a document and that's resulting in the following Traceback in the production builds:

```
2:42:19 PM: /opt/build/repo/node_modules/@prismicio/helpers/dist/documentToLinkField.cjs:9
2:42:19 PM:     uid: prismicDocument.uid ?? void 0,
2:42:19 PM:                               ^
2:42:19 PM: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
2:42:19 PM:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
2:42:19 PM:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
2:42:19 PM:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2:42:19 PM:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
2:42:19 PM:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
2:42:19 PM:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
2:42:19 PM:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2:42:19 PM:     at Module.<anonymous> (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@prismicio/helpers/dist/asLink.cjs:4:29)
2:42:19 PM:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
2:42:19 PM:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10) {
2:42:19 PM:   type: 'SyntaxError'
```

In my code itself using `@prismicio/client`, I am creating a Client object:

```js
import * as prismic from "@prismicio/client";

const repositoryName = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PRISMIC_REPO_NAME;
const endpoint = prismic.getRepositoryEndpoint(repositoryName);

export const createClient = () => {
    return prismic.createClient(endpoint, {
        accessToken: process.env.PRISMIC_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    });
};
```

and later, I am using the client by pulling in content from a UID I created:

```js
let contentBlob = await client.getByUID("customUID", params.partner);
```

This works well locally, and all of the copy changes are reflected in the local rendered output. Besides deleting and/or recreating documents and adding in logs where I can, are there best practices for debugging this (somewhat mysterious) Prismic error?

Comment: Looks like the environment in which you are running this code does not yet support the `??` operator. Consider upgrading the nodejs version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version of `@prismicio/client` contains code using nullish coalescing (the `??` operator).

It’s possible you are using a version of Node.js in production (i.e. Netlify) that does not support `??`. It is supported as of Node.js 14.

Updating your Netlify build environment to use at least Node.js 14 should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! Setting the `NODE_VERSION` in my environment variables did the trick!